# Find the force from 2 people holding a ladder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque

A child and an adult are holding a ladder 4 m long and 195 N in weight. The child is located 1 m from the extreme left and the adult 1.5 m from the extreme right.

How can I find the applied force from the adult and the applied force from the boy? If someone knows please help if you want to.[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase your last line, "How do I calculate....from the adult a the boy?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question

Comment: Read " equilibrium of torque "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the weight of the ladder is evenly distributed, then I think you can solve this problem using the concept of torque and force. Since the ladder is stationary and not rotating, we know that the **net torque** and the **net force** acting on it about **its centre of mass** are both 0.

Since the weight is evenly distributed, the centre of mass will be $1m$ from the kid, and $0.5m$ from the adult, then you can calculate the net torque as $$F_{child}(1m)=F_{adult}(0.5m)$$.

But there are two unknowns, which are the force applied by child and the force applied by the adult($F_{child}$ and $F_{adult}$),and you can't solve for 2 unknowns with only 1 equation. So you may need to write out another equation to show that the **net force** acting on it is also 0. Thus you get $$F_{child}+F_{adult}-mg=0$$

Then you can solve the two equations simultaneously for two unknowns. Hope this help.

Comment: using the two equations plus the mg=195 I resolve the question. Fc=65 and Fa=130. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome 